# Issues with EE Flickr for ExpressionEngine and favorited photos

Tags: extension

I'm using EE hive's [flickr plugin](http://www.ee-hive.com/add-ons/flickr-for-expressionengine/). I've authenticated ExpressionEngine with my flickr account but i'm having issues getting the favorites tag pair to display any information. I'm using EE 2.5.3 and the extension is version 2.1.9.

**Here's my testing code**

```
<h1>Photo stream</h1>
{exp:eehive_flickr:photostream}{flickr_url}<br />{/exp:eehive_flickr:photostream}

<h1>Sets</h1>
{exp:eehive_flickr:photosets}{set_url}<br />{/exp:eehive_flickr:photosets}

<h1>Favorites</h1>
{exp:eehive_flickr:favorites}{flickr_img}<br />{/exp:eehive_flickr:favorites}
```

The favorites tag pair just returns the `{flickr_img}` variable in plain text.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are the other components being returned properly? The regular photo stream, not the favorites? Also, for the favorites, did you check to see if any of the other tags render, {flickr_url_orig}, {flickr_title}, {flickr_description}? That will help determine if the tag pair isn't working or if something else is going on.

Comment: The photo stream and sets are working properly. The favorites won't render any tags inside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK I found the bug. I'll get in touch with Digital Wax Works to update the add-on, but in the meantime here's your fix:

Open up /system/expressionengine/third_party/eehive_flickr/pi.eehive_flickr.php, and at around line 310 you should find:

```
// Retrieve favorites from Flickr
$favorites = $f->favorites_getPublicList($flickr_settings['option_nsid'], NULL, NULL, $this->api_extras, $numPhotos, 1);
```

That method call is missing a parameter, so add another NULL in there like so:

```
$favorites = $f->favorites_getPublicList($flickr_settings['option_nsid'], NULL, NULL, NULL, $this->api_extras, $numPhotos, 1);
```

Give that a go, I hope it works for you!

Cheers,
John